# Apache Spark slow on reduceByKey step

Tags: python, performance, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a 2MB plain text file in /usr/local/share/data/.
And then I run against the following code in Apache Spark.

```
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("test").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g") 
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
doc_rdd = sc.textFile("/usr/local/share/data/")
unigrams = doc_rdd.flatMap(word_tokenize)
step1 = unigrams.flatMap(word_pos_tagging)
step2 = step1.filter(lambda x: filter_punctuation(x[0]))
step3 = step2.map(lambda x: (x, 1))
freq_unigrams = step3.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

**Expected result**

```
[((u'showing', 'VBG'), 24), ((u'Ave', 'NNP'), 1), ((u'Scrilla364', 'NNP'), 1), ((u'internally', 'RB'), 4), ...]
```

But it takes very very long time (6 minutes) to return the expected word count.
It stucks at reduceByKey steps.
*How to resolve this performance issue?*

-- Reference --

**Hardware Specification**

Model Name: MacBook Air Model
Identifier: MacBookAir4,2
Processor Name: Intel Core i7 Processor
Speed: 1.8 GHz
Number of Processors: 1
Total Number of Cores: 2
L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
L3 Cache: 4 MB
Memory: 4 GB

**Log**

```
15/10/02 16:05:12 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/usr/local/share/data/enronsent01:0+873602
15/10/02 16:05:12 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/usr/local/share/data/enronsent01:873602+873602
15/10/02 16:09:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on localhost:53478 in memory (size: 4.1 KB, free: 530.0 MB)
15/10/02 16:09:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on localhost:53478 in memory (size: 4.6 KB, free: 530.0 MB)
15/10/02 16:09:11 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 4
15/10/02 16:09:11 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 3
15/10/02 16:09:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on localhost:53478 in memory (size: 3.9 KB, free: 530.0 MB)
15/10/02 16:09:11 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 2
15/10/02 16:10:05 INFO PythonRDD: Times: total = 292892, boot = 8, init = 275, finish = 292609
15/10/02 16:10:05 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4). 2373 bytes result sent to driver
15/10/02 16:10:05 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4) in 292956 ms on localhost (1/2)
15/10/02 16:10:35 INFO PythonRDD: Times: total = 322562, boot = 5, init = 276, finish = 322281
15/10/02 16:10:35 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3). 2373 bytes result sent to driver
15/10/02 16:10:35 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) in 322591 ms on localhost (2/2)
```

Comment: How many partitions were created? doc_rdd.partitions.length or would be no of tasks executed.

Comment: same problem...  Any final answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine.

You can try few options to improve performance.

```
SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("test").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
```

`local` -> `local[*]` if the task is broken - it can take the number of core available on the machine
And if possible increase the memory available to the program

P.S. And to appreciate Spark - you should have a good amount of data so as you can run it on cluster

Comment: I try setting to local[*] or local[2] but the problem still exists.

Comment: More information on my hardware specification:
Hardware Overview:
  Model Name: MacBook Air
  Model Identifier: MacBookAir4,2
  Processor Name: Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed: 1.8 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 2
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 4 MB
  Memory: 4 GB

Comment: Do .set("spark.executor.memory", "3g") so as to increase the memory available for the program

Comment: @SimonHo : Are you planning to run the Spark on Cluster? As the  Standalone mode is used for development of the program. If not then try to do this stuff by normal Python program.

Comment: Of course I plan to run as Cluster mode in Production. I expect more files of bigger size would've processed.

Comment: Reduce By Key does the aggregation at Executor and then at  Driver.So it takes a bit more time instead you can add one more step of partitioning the data by HashMap or some custom partitioner to reduce the time >>> step2.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).partitionBy(2).glom(). Have not used pyspark much so not sure but in Scala HashMap partitioning is present.

Comment: I tried with and without partitioning, the results don't differ much. The reduceByKey task completes in 6 minutes (which I don't expect that long).

Comment: from the Spark INFO log, the issue shouldn't be caused by memory. I put some more information on the description.

Comment: Since you are doing local development and the data is small for development.Make only one partition i.e coalesce into one partition and do it.It will speed up the task.

Comment: I tried: `step3 = step2.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).coalesce(1, shuffle = True)`. It doesn't really speed up the task. @iamAGin, would you try this piece of code running against a 2MB file locally?

Comment: @SimonHo : I tried using 4 MB file and its taking very less time to do that stuff. **Ok I got it**. You need to know about lazy evalutation in Spark. Its not that the reduce by key is taking long time. In Spark : there is Transformation and Action.All the map operation is transformation.It does not get executed unless an action task is performed like collect or take.So it might seem that reduce by key is taking a long time but there are other processes running at back to get the data to reduceByKey to perform and then print/save.

Comment: I got what you meant now. I try the very simple example from official Apache Spark documentation and I run against both Scala and Python Spark Shell. It runs fast. So probably the word_tokenize or/and word_pos_tagging functions does something slow. I try to share those functions at later time, before we get into a conclusion and close by an upvote. You are my savior.

Comment: @SimonHo : As per my experience with NLP word_pos_tagging - will be slow as we need to create a dependency tree with the phrases in the sentence . So thats probably killing the time.

Comment: right, I am using NLTK pos tagging. After I remove the pos tagging function from the chain, it runs about 10 seconds. I guess you have answered my question. So I give an upvote.