# Spark on localhost

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

For testing purposes, while I don´t have production cluster, I am using spark locally:

```
print('Setting SparkContext...')
sconf = SparkConf()
sconf.setAppName('myLocalApp')
sconf.setMaster('local[*]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=sconf)
print('Setting SparkContext...OK!')
```

Also, I am using a very very small dataset, consisting of only 20 rows in a postgresql database ( ~2kb)

Also(!), my code is quite simple as well, only grouping **20 rows** by a key and applying a trivial map operation

```
params = [object1, object2]
rdd = df.rdd.keyBy(lambda x: (x.a, x.b, x.c)) \
                          .groupByKey() \
                          .mapValues(lambda value: self.__data_interpolation(value, params))


def __data_interpolation(self, data, params):
    # TODO: only for testing
    return data
```

What bothers me is that the whole execution takes about **5 minutes!!**

Inspecting the Spark UI, I see that most of the time was spent in Stage 6: byKey method. (Stage 7, collect() method was also slow...)

Some info:

[image]

[image]

These numbers make no sense to me... Why do I need 22 tasks, executing for 54 sec, to process less than 1 kb of data

Can it be a network issue, trying to figure out the ip address of localhost?
I don't know... Any clues?

Comment: looks like this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900135/apache-spark-slow-on-reducebykey-step

Comment: I can provide any other debug info, if needed...

Comment: Is it possible to try putting the same data as lines in a text file and running on that instead of reading it from a postgres database?  5 minutes seems pathologically slow to shuffle essentially no data and perform a nop transformation on it.  It makes me think maybe there's an issue accessing the data that's manifesting as slow operations on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the main reason for the slower performance in your code snippet is due to the use of `groupByKey()`.  The issue with `groupByKey` is that it ends up shuffling all of the key-value pairs resulting in a lot of data unnecessarily being transferred.  A good reference to explain this issue is [Avoid GroupByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html).

To work around this issue, you can:

1. Try using `reduceByKey` which should be faster (more info is also included in the above Avoid GroupByKey link).
2. Use DataFrames (instead of RDDs) as DFs include performance optimizations (and the DF GroupBy statement is faster than the RDD version).  As well, as you're using Python, you can avoid the Python-to-JVM issues with PySpark RDDs.  More information on this can be seen in [PySpark Internals](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals)

By the way, reviewing the Spark UI diagram above, the #22 refers to the task # within the DAG (not the number of tasks executed).

HTH!

Comment: Good point about the task #22. But the task count starts at 0, so it is really 22 tasks being executed... Since it is quite difficult to pinpoint the exact error, this answer is the best so far. Btw:@mariusz has a good answer too

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the "postgresql" is the key to solve that puzzle.

`keyBy` is probably the first operation that really uses the data so it's execution time is bigger as it needs to get the data from external database. You can verify it by adding at the beginning:

```
df.cache()
df.count() # to fill the cache
df.rdd.keyBy....
```

If I am right, you need to optimize the database. It may be:

1. Network issue (slow network to DB server)
2. Complicated (and slow) SQL on this database (try it using postgre shell)
3. Some authorization difficulties on DB server
4. Problem with JDBC driver you use

Comment: Good answer too...  I will look at it

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen happening in my system while running spark:

When we run a spark job it internally creates map and reduce tasks and runs them. In your case, to run the data you have, it created 22 such tasks. I bigger the size of data the number may be big.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you looking for anything specific?